# Server vs Serverless for REST API

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I have a REST API that I was thinking about deploying using a Serverless model. My data is in an AWS RDS server that needs to be put in a VPC for security reasons. To allow a Lambda to access the RDS, I need to configure the lambda to be in a VPC, but this makes cold starts an average of 8 seconds longer according to articles I read.

The REST API is for a website so an 8 second page load is not acceptable.

Is there anyway I can use a Serverless model to implement my REST API or should I just use a regular EC2 server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not yet released, but let us hope that this is a matter of weeks/months now. At re:Invent 2018 AWS has introduced [Remote NAT for Lambda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdzV04T_kec&feature=youtu.be&t=2393) to be available this year (2019).

For now you have to either expose RDS to the outside (directly or through a tunnel), but this is a security issue. Or Create Lambda ENIs in VPC.

In order to keep your Lambdas "warm" you may create a scheduled "ping" mechanism. Some example of this pattern you can find in the [Article of Yan Cui](https://hackernoon.com/im-afraid-you-re-thinking-about-aws-lambda-cold-starts-all-wrong-7d907f278a4f).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Does this mean pretty much no one is using lambdas for a REST API if they are using RDS? I have heard how easy it is to create a REST API with serverless, so I assumed there must be a way to do it seeing how ubiquitous SQL is.

Comment: I, personally, use Lambdas in the VPC for REST API working with DBs (not only RDS, but also Mongo hosted on EC2). Firstly, the cold start is usually much faster than the mentioned maximum and is 1-3 secs. Secondly, the container normally lives up to 24 hours and having tens of thousands of calls per container usually neglects the problem of a single cold-start. I do not even  "pre-warm" them. This is a common scenario, even having this small cold-start issue.